# How to theme the ctools modal window

Tags: modal-dialog, themes, drupal-6, drupal-ctools

Does anybody know how I can theme the ctools modal window? I've tried putting the css that it comes with in my own theme to over-ride it, but that is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a super easy question to answer. I'm putting the answer here just in case someone else runs into the same problem I did:

My mistake was that I did not know that it wasn't  enough to just include a ***modal.css*** file in my themes folder.

To correctly **override** a **css** file for a core/contributed module, the **theme.info** file edited to refer to that css:

```
stylesheets[all][] = modal.css
```

More information can be found at http://drupal.org/node/263967

Answer (score 3):

some tips for ctools docs ctools\help\modal.html

```
drupal_add_js(array(
    'CToolsModal' => array(
      'modalSize' => array(
        'type' => 'fixed',
        'width' => 450,
        'height' => 350,
        'contentBottom' => 800), 
    ),
  ), 'setting');
```